# Give DateEnd when ServiceId changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Currently, in my table all end dates are null. However, this can sometimes cause duplicates if the `ServiceId` changes because of a mistake made on the previous entry and we have multiple instances in a column that should be unique.

So what I want to do is rearrange this query to say something like when the `ServiceId` changes to provide a `DateEnd`. currently, if you look at the logic it says `DateEnd` is null. Help is greatly appreciated

```
right JOIN ods.Service ods ON Convert(NVARCHAR(20),dbo.number) = ods.number
    AND ods.DateEnd IS NULL AND ods.ServiceId = dbo.ServiceNumber
```

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will really help us help you here.

Comment: Also mention the SQL Server Version you are using.

Comment: so an instance where I may have duplicates would be like this:                                  DateId:20190730 ServiceId:1234 AccountNumber:123456 CallId:69489 Date:2019-06-20 DateEnd: Null                                                                                  DateId:20190730 ServiceId:null AccountNumber:123456 CallId:6780948 Date:2019-07-20 DateEnd:Null                                                                                  Whenever the serviceId changes I need an enddate. I would like to add it to the first instance